# Dropzone Apollo-upload-client using Upload! Type

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, react-apollo, react-dropzone

I am using `apollo-upload-client` (so graphQL) and am trying to use dropzone to upload files to my server.

I have done this successfully using `<input required onChange={({ target: { validity, files: [file] } })=> this._uploadFiles(validity, file)}` with the function

```
_uploadFiles = async (validity, file) => {
        if (validity.valid){
            await this.props.addImageFileMutation({
                variables: {file}
            })
        }
    }
```

For Dropzone, I have:

```
<Dropzone
                      onDrop={this._onDrop.bind(this)}
                      multiple={false}>
                    </Dropzone>
```

using the function:

```
_onDrop = async (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) => {
        const firstFile = acceptedFiles[0]
        await this.props.addImageFileMutation({
            variables: { firstFile }
        })
    }
```

**Here are the files that are sent from each, they look the same to me! But it only works from `<input />`!**
The first value is using `<Dropzone />`, the second value is using `<input />`.

[image]

**Do you know why I am getting this `$file` not matching `Upload!` issue? I have added some more code below for reference.**

```
const ADD_IMAGE_FILE_MUTATION = gql`
mutation AddImageFileMutation ($file: Upload!) {
    addImageFile(file: $file){
        id
}}`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `_onDrop`, you are passing a variable named `firstFile` to your mutation, but it's looking for a variable named `file`:

```
variables: { firstFile }
```

Try this instead:

```
variables: { file: firstFile }
```

Comment: Daniel, I totally appreciate it, I can't believe the fix was that easy, thank you!

Comment: I have run against this issue at least twice, and I think your solution was what solved it first too, Thanks a lot!